How to quote Alexander from Julian's satire "The Caesars" for an epithet
I want to quote the phrase "I am aware that you Romans are yourselves descended from the Greeks, and that the greater part of Italy was colonized by Greeks;" however, I cant attribute it to Alexander, because he did not say that, nor to Julian, because he's speaking through the character of Alexander. I'm not sure how to correctly attribute the quote in epithet form.

The source for your quote is Julian's satire The Caesars, so that is what you must give as a source if you want to attribute it correctly. You may explain that it is the character Alexander who says it. E.g.

I am aware that you Romans are yourselves descended from the Greeks, and that the greater part of Italy was colonized by Greeks.
— Alexander in Julian's The Caesars

The Chicago Manual of Style explains the conventional formatting of epigraphs and gives the following exemple:

Oh, what a tangled web we weave,
When first we practice to deceive!
—Sir Walter Scott

The quote is from Scott's historical verse romance Marmion, where the verses are part of a direct speech that is spoken by the titular character, Lord Marmion. As you can see, the example, as given in the Chicago Manual of Style (in section 13.36 of the 17th print edition), makes no mention of which character says those words and only gives the well-known author as the source, even omitting the work's title.
If we use this as an example, we might style your quote in the following way:

I am aware that you Romans are yourselves descended from the Greeks, and that the greater part of Italy was colonized by Greeks.
— Julian


Note that the line giving the author is usually right-aligned, which is not possible on this site.
